# Incorrect VAT calculation by Magento after discount

Tags: magento, discount

Ok, here’s the problem: I’ve set up my website and it is all working fine. I’ve got one problem: On the last step of Onepagecheckout, Magento calculates TAX over the total amount and disgards discount. In the shopping cart, on the invoice and the amount that’s send to the paymentsite is correct; only on the last page it’s wrong. An example:

Someone buy’s 2 products, total 209,45 including VAT. The VAT amount is (19%) 33,44. However, he receives a € 17 discount. Total price is now 192,45 and the VAT should be 30,73. This is the amount that is shown on the invoice and the shoppingcart. However, on the last step of the onepagecheckout, the total amount is 195,16. So Magento calculates the VAT based on the price before discount, then adds it to the amount ex VAT after discount.

Magento is set to calculate VAT over the total amount, after discount and i use 1.4.2. It’s a live website, so i can’t fidel about to much.

I’ve seen a lot of people with this problem and the problem is always disgarded as some setting being wrong, so i will say it again: On the invoice, in the shopping cart and the amount that’s send to the paymentgateway; it’s all correct, it’s just the last step that’s displaying the total amount wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your tax settings in system > config > Tax change 'Apply Customer Tax' to 'After Discount'

Comment: That's not it; like i said, it's only at the last page, no where else! If it was a problem with the configuration, the tax would be wrong everywhere...